# How to track and log UITableViewCell views as the user scrolls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, analytics

How can we track each UITableViewCell view as the user scrolls down in UITableView? The user needs to view the cell for a while (1 second) to count it as a view.

Basic tracking below does not give accurate results because the user may scroll real fast and it shall not be counted as a cell view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    [self logCellView:indexPath objectId:object.objectId];
}
```

or

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self logCellView:indexPath objectId:object.objectId];
}
```

then

```
-(void)logCellView:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath objectId:(NSString *)objectId {
    // Log the cell view with any analytics tool here
}
```

Comment: try using willDisplayCell: method

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Thanks @BhushanUparkar. Method willDisplayCell is kinda the same with cellForRowAtIndexPath since the action is triggered as soon as cell is viewed. I'm trying to achieve logging if the cell is viewed for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a custom cell:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval time;

@end
```

Main code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *myCell = (MyCell *)cell;
    myCell.time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *myCell = (MyCell *)cell;
    NSTimeInterval startTime = myCell.time;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if (currentTime - startTime >= 1) {
        NSLog(@"Logging.. %i.Row Display Time = %f", indexPath.row, currentTime-startTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be below but is there a more stable & safe way?

```
-(void)logCellView:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(NSString *)object {
    // Set the timer to log the view since we don't want to log fast scrolls
    if (indexPath.row >= [logViewTimers count] && object) {
        [logViewTimers insertObject:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(logCellViewQuery:) userInfo:object repeats:NO] atIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        // Cell is viewed again, set a longer interval
        [logViewTimers replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(logCellViewQuery:) userInfo:object repeats:NO]];
    }
}

-(void)logCellViewQuery:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
     NSLog (@"Will save the log for: %@", (NSString*)[theTimer userInfo]);
    // Query here (hidden for security)
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Gone indexPath: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    // Kill the timer to log the view since user scrolled fast
    if (indexPath.row < [logViewTimers count]) {
        if (((NSTimer*)[logViewTimers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])) {
            [((NSTimer*)[logViewTimers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) invalidate];
        }
    }
}
```